# Python crashes when retrieving large amounts of data from server

Tags: python, memory, cmd, memory-leaks, crash

I have my code split into different functions, called by button presses. I can import data and upload it to my Google CloudSQL/localhost, and also display/modify the database using a GUI I designed with Tkinter. My code works for a small, sample dataset (I've tried with 4 rows at first, then 50. At 100+, it crashes. Using Jupyter the error I received was "The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically.". When I run the .py file via cmd, I get the error: "Failed to create the menu window".

In order to replicate my issue here's the code laid out for you to get started. MySQL:

database creation:

```
    CREATE DATABASE mydatabase;
```

table creation:

```
    CREATE TABLE Registration1 (
id int(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
FullName varchar(100),
DOB date,
JoinAge varchar(10),
JoinGrade varchar(5),
FatherName varchar(100),
FatherCell varchar(15),
FatherEmail varchar(100),
MotherName varchar(100),
MotherCell varchar(15),
MotherEmail varchar(100),
HomePhone varchar(15),
Ethnicity varchar(30),
ReferralType varchar(50),
ReferredBy varchar(100),
School varchar(100),
Preference varchar(100),
Comments varchar(500),
Active tinyint(1),
Misc tinyint(1),
Followup tinyint(1)
    );
```

My python file is available here: https://ufile.io/m443k9sg

My Sample Excel File is available here: https://ufile.io/kq08kbc0

All you need to do is ensure your the table is created as above, and you are able to import the excel rows into the database using the 'Import from Excel' button (once). Clicking Display should work for small number of rows, but if you just copy paste the 4 all the way down to 100+ rows, you (should?) see the error I'm having. I've included some print statements in the console to act as a log to see how my code is iterating through.

As described earlier, I expect the results to be the same as when I have a small dataset, of course slightly slower. Yet I'm unable to pinpoint the exact issue of my problem. Is it a memory leak? Is it lack of RAM? (I don't think it's a RAM issue as I've viewed my Task Manager while the process runs, and it doesn't fluctuate very high). Any and all help would be appreciated! I'm still fairly new to python/db querying, I have some basics down but could probably work a lot on efficiency. Hopefully the setup isn't too much for helpers to go through. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may consider to read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Netwave, thank you, I've minimized the amount of work needed from a user to replicate my error by providing files. As for snippetting, I don't think it is terribly relevant as my code works for small datasets - it's more that the display doesn't show when incorporating a large data set from server.